# Phonegap with angular JS ng-view cant go full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, cordova

I'm aware some people already asked this. I have tried those answers but no luck for now.

This is some important parts of my `index.html` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<body> 
    <div ng-view>    
       <!--MY CONTENT HERE-->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

I loaded my content to `<div ng-view>`. Its loaded successfully but the height is not full. The height just depend on the content.

This is the summary of my loaded content :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="topcoat-list__container scroller">
        <ul class="topcoat-list list">
            <li class="topcoat-list__item">
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS :

```
html, body, .parent { height: 100vh; width: 100%; margin: 0; /*position:absolute;*/}
```

I have tried `height:100%` with `position:absolute;` but no luck at all.
I used `topcoat` library in my loaded content, but i think it should be no problem.

Please kindly help me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why not try [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) - it's pretty much phone gap for angular

Comment: Err...sorry im very new with hybrid development. So if i use Ionic, i dont have to use Phonegap? Or is it just a CSS + JS?

Comment: And it said we will need to pay after they are going beta?

Comment: Ionic is just a framework for Phonegap built off of Angular - it's hard to explain, but I'm using it for a personal project, and it's pretty awesome. It's current released, except for Ionic push notifications, but you can still use your own server (Ionic made a Push Notification as a service thing). But yeah, it's free and it does what you need. You should read the docs to understand it better (I'm awful at explaining this stuff :P)

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry guys, my `CSS` path is wrong. It seems i need to take a break LOL
Anyway, the code in my question is working :)